# PhoneGap and Appaccelerator apps are legal for iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, mobile, cordova

I want to create mobile apps for the iPhone and Android and Im wondering if PhoneGap and Appaccelerator are allowed in iPhone 4 due to the section 3.3.1.

Do they know the case now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Appcelerator, but PhoneGap is ok for sure.

http://www.phonegap.com/2010/04/14/phonegap-and-the-apple-developer-license-agreement/